# How can I use NSMapTable with String keys in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swift3

In earlier versions of Swift, it was possible to have the keys in my NSMapTable be strings:

```
let mapTable = NSMapTable(keyOptions: .StrongMemory, valueOptions: .WeakMemory)
...
mapTable.setObject(..., forKey: "foo")
```

Per: http://nshipster.com/nshashtable-and-nsmaptable/

In Swift 3, NSMapTable needs generic parameters. But when I try to do:

```
NSMapTable<String, MyClass>(keyOptions: .strongMemory, valueOptions: .weakMemory)
```

I get a `"Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'"` error.

What is the correct way to have the keys of my NSMapTable be strings in Swift 3?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wouldn't say your own answer was a "hack", just more general than needed, use:

```
NSMapTable<NSString, MyClass>(keyOptions: .strongMemory, valueOptions: .weakMemory)
...
mapTable.setObject(..., forKey: "foo")
```

Comment: Ahh - duh! Thanks.

Comment: It took me 5 minutes of scanning to spot the difference between yours and the original. I see that your key type is NSString where the original was String.

Comment: Thank you... life saver.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question.

This seems to work:

```
NSMapTable<AnyObject, MyClass>(keyOptions: .strongMemory, valueOptions: .weakMemory)
...
mapTable.setObject(..., forKey: "foo")
```

This feels kind of like a hack to me though?